# PHP short syntax for [IF] exists and equall

Tags: php, variables, syntax

just wondering if there is a short version of this expression:

```
if(!empty($var) && $var == 'FOO')
{
 // Do things
}
```

It checks if `$var` `IS DEFINED`, `NOT FALSE`, `NOT NULL` and `NOT EQUAL TO ZERO`. And only if `$var` meets these requirements, the second part of the condition kicks in and checks if `$var == 'FOO'`.

Of course, i can do it this way: `if($var == 'FOO'){}` but in case if `$var` is not defined it will throw a `Notice`.

Just tested this code:

```
$var='FOO';

if (!empty($var)=='FOO')
{
 echo 'BLAH'; 
}
// Will output 'BLAH'
```

But it will out-put `BLAH` in ANY case when `!empty($var)` returns `TRUE`. Since string `'FOO'` -> `IS DEFINED`, `NOT FALSE`, `NOT NULL` and `NOT EQUAL TO ZERO` it will output `BLAH`. Meaning `!empty($var)=='FOO'` only judges `$var` by its appearance not by whats inside. Not gonna work in my case.

Any ideas?

Comment: why does it need to be shorter than that?

Comment: Well if there is a a shorter way i would gladly use it. If not then i will use it as it is or, as you suggested, woll create a function :)

Comment: @smerny i like to be concise.

Comment: IF var has something, like 'FOO', then it's not going to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own function to do it.

```
if (myFunction($var, 'foo')) ...
```

And the function would look like:

```
public function myFunction($var, $expectedVar) {
// check if empty and equal
}
```

Comment: Notice on undefined variable.

Comment: "empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist."